# MonoTouch Activation/Reactivation

Tags: mono, migration, xamarin.ios, activation

I'm having the most frustrating time with MonoTouch/Mono/Monodevelop. After using the app for nearly six months I, foolishly, decided to get a new computer. I used Apple's Migration Assistant to move everything over, and it went perfectly.

Except I can no longer compile due to a need for reactivation of my license. Well, the folks at MonoTouch got rid of the activation app. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling in hopes that the activation screen would return -- no dice. Can someone point me in the right direction?

1) I need to find the activation application that Mono's own installation instructions allude to here: http://monotouch.net/Releases/MonoTouch_4/MonoTouch_4.0.0 (I know activation is apparently bundled with the app now -- but how would anyone ever reactivate?)

2) How does the reactivation process work?

I'm quite frustrated now considering I've paid 400 dollars for something that I'm not allowed to use if I ever want to upgrade my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question to Attachmate who stopped supporting the Monotouch. You are not alone there, best answer is, go and ask for a refund from Novell/Attachmate as they do not support you anymore.

You need to wait until the new venture xamarin.com is up and release they successor to the Monotouch solution from Novell.

Comment: I called Novell, they apparently fired everyone and they don't have much in the way of help for me. Is there no way to move any of my old files to the new machine? Is there some license file buried somewhere that I don't know about that needs to be transferred?

Comment: Well the license file is located at your user profile directory under ~/Library/MonoTouch

this file is named License.v2, you can try to put it on another machine, never tried that, but I guess some sort of machine identification is put there. Let us know if it helped.